# new HiveConf exception NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I'm running HiveConf tests, and always get exception when new HiveConf saying that "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper"

I tried to explicitly add this jar dependency in maven pom.xml, but no effect.
Any idea how to solve this? I'm using hive 2.3.5.

Comment: Finally solved this issue. It's weird that I had hadoop common jar and hive-jdbc jar in my java ext library. Thus when loading hadoop common dependencies like this one, the class loader only uses ext loader, not app loader, and the dependencies couldn't be found.

Comment: Just remove these jars from Java/Extensions library and it will be fine